# Express CORS not working

Tags: node.js, api, express, cors

I just started my nodejs express template buy cors is not working.

I used npm install cors --save

here is the file:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.com/',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

app.get('/tt', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Now with the above code when I access localhost:3030/tt or / I still see the content and I shouldn't

What's wrong with this.. I just lost like 2 hours working on this.. :( 
At this time I would like not to use CORS, but in near future when my app is finished, I want to allow incoming calls only from my project, since this app will be my API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are describing seems is what I would expect.

CORS won't help you filter out incoming calls on the server.   In this case the browser's CORS check won't kick-in as it appears you are directly typing in the URL in the browser.   Browser does a CORS check only when the the webpage loaded from a particular domain tries to access/submit to a URL in a different domain.

A different way to think about CORS.   CORS is intended to protect the user sitting in front of the browser,  and not the server-code that is being accessed.

Comment: thank you for your reply. How would it best be to prototect my apiserver.com to allow access only from mywebpage.com ?

Comment: API user authentication and tokens will help you only allowing you using the API